# SUM value wrong show from two tables

Tags: sql, sum, subquery

```
SELECT
    SUM(fabricinventory.sqty) AS shipped,
    SUM(fabricinventory.rcvd) AS received
FROM
    (SELECT
         SUM(requisition.issue) AS issue
     FROM
         requisition
     INNER JOIN 
         fabricinventory ON fabricinventory.id = requisition.fab_id
     GROUP BY
         fabricinventory.buyer_id,
         fabricinventory.file_id);
```

When I input subquery, I get a syntax error.

Can you please help me with the correct syntax?

Comment: Your subquery is missing its alias, but that aside, I don't even see the point of the subquery.  Please add some sample data.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0):

try my code :

```
SELECT
    SUM(shipped) AS shipped,
    SUM(received) AS received
FROM
    (
    SELECT
         fabricinventory.sqty AS shipped,
         fabricinventory.rcvd  AS received,
        SUM(requisition.issue) AS issue
    FROM
        requisition
    INNER JOIN fabricinventory ON fabricinventory.id = requisition.fab_id

GROUP BY
    fabricinventory.sqty,
    fabricinventory.rcvd) sub_query
    ;
```

When you use subquery behind FROM you must add an alias to the query

Comment: Dear, Thanks for response but it showing wrong data